# What is the proper way to reset attiny85?

Tags: stm32, reset, attiny85

I have 3 attiny85 on my pcb. And I want to have software controlled reset for them. A separate STM32F0 microcontroller is responsible for the reset. I have two states from the STM32F0 to pull up and pull down an IO pin. And I have directly connected the output of this IO pin to IO2 on this schematic. And the RESET pin on this schematic goes directly to the 3 reset pins of the 3 attiny85 chips in parallel. So, basically if the stm32f0 is powered off, I want the attiny85 chips to be in an ever lasting reset state or non-functional state. As soon as the stm32 comes online, and it pulls the IO2 ping high through software code, I want the attiny chips to be functional again and running their specific firmware codes. Now, if the stm32f0 for any reason want to just reset the attinys, a software pull down of the IO2 pin should reset the all 3 attiny together. That's the plan. Not sure if the circuit diagram show below is the proper way to do this. Need some suggestions on how to achieve this goal.

[image]

BTW both the stm32f0 and attiny85 is running on 3.3V supply thus making them both compatible in terms of 3.3V logic.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes, it will work as you suggest.

Comment: You could also leave out the resistors and just connect all of the pins directly together.

Comment: @jusaca The question is whether it is the proper way to do what I want to do. Is there any better way for this? Will this hurt the attiny by any mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99783/discussion-between-dave-tweed-and-farukh).